# Laravel: When I pass a model to a controller it is always null. Why?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to change my ways in Laravel, but I find it quite frustrating

Normally, in a controller I'd write something like this

```
public function edit($id) {
    $question = Question::findOrFail($id);
    return view('question.edit', compact('question');
}
```

This obviously works. In the HTML the route that calls this is `{{ route('question.edit', $question->id) }}`. Now I want to use the method it is written by Artisan when you create the controller. If I do:

```
public function edit(Question $question) {
    return view('question.edit', compact('question');
}
```

This doesn't work (of course I'm changing the blade directive to `{{ route('question.edit', $question) }}`), this always passes an empty `Question` model, it doesn't have id or any of the other fields that were accessible in the blade file. If I do a `dd()` in the blade file, it'll show the correct model, when passed to the Controller is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On your route its `$id`, not `$question`. Change it `{id}` to `{question}`

Comment: in the route definition in the `web.php`? ‍♂️ I'll try that

Comment: That should work, because you need to use same name param

Comment: Yes it worked!!! Thanks a lot. All my routes had `{id}`s. I never thought the name was important! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match your type hinted variable name to the name of the route parameter if you want Implicit Model Binding to work, otherwise you are just asking for a dependency and it will inject a new instance of that model:

```
//                    vvvvvvvv
Route::get('question/{question}/edit', 'YourController@edit');

//                             vvvvvvvv
public function edit(Question $question)
```